# Which construction for iteration is better to use in Scala?

Tags: performance, scala, coding-style

Recently, I've start to code a lot of my programming competitions in Scala. (You could take a look at platform here - http://codeforces.com/)

Regarding nature of problems, I often need to iterate over array or over input data. E.g. there is a problem statement, which said, that on first input line I will get number M and then I need to read M lines, or integers or whatever. I try to use different approach for that:

```
for (i <- 0 until M)
---- 
(0 until M).foreach
----
var i = 0
while (i < M)
---
```

Or even tail recursion

```
@tailrec
  def recursion(i: Int): Unit = {
    if (i < M) {
      doSomething()
      recursion(i + 1)
    }
  }
```

So, my question is which construction is better to use regarding Scala style and for better **performance**? (problems that I am solving are often requires fast execution, or they will not be passed)

P.S.
I write a small test for that, and it looks like while and tailrec is the best performer, but not for a big matter. You could look at it here - https://gist.github.com/MysterionRise/5daa63fdbd5d058528fe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding performance :**

Note that if you want to write proper micro-benchmarks on the JVM, you have to account for [many effects](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/MicroBenchmarks) - for instance, the performance of the same piece of code will vary at first as the JVM starts using JIT compilation, and then trying different optimizations. To write proper benchmarks in Scala, you can have a look at libraries like [ScalaMeter](http://scalameter.github.io/) or [caliper](http://www.decodified.com/scala/2011/04/19/microbenchmarking-scala-code.html) for instance. Incidentally, the second link compares different ways to loop in Scala, so it should be easy to adapt to your use case.

However, generally speaking:

- The tail recursive solution will be optimized to the same sort of bytecode that would be produced by an equivalent while loop, so the two should always be similar (if the code is really equivalent).
- the for loop is syntactic sugar for a call to the foreach method, so the two should be strictly equivalent.
- foreach (or for loop) is somewhat slower than an equivalent while loop (or tail recursion): the [benchmark](http://www.decodified.com/scala/2011/04/19/microbenchmarking-scala-code.html) I linked to above shows a 15x performance difference with 1000+ iterations (though it will likely depend on the version of Scala and the version of the JRE...). But that difference will become negligible if the code inside the loop takes much longer to execute than the loop itself, so that doesn't mean it's always relevant.

**Regarding style :**

I entirely agree with johanandren's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would rate them for style in the following order:

- for/foreach
- tail recursion
- imperative while (last resort stylewise)

Regarding performance tail recursion and imperative will give you as fast as looping goes (tailrec will in practice become something very close to a while loop), and are faster than the for/foreach ones.

A side note: if you are going for ideomatic Scala you might want to try to avoid side effecting and instead use `.map` or make your tail recursive function return something rather than mutate something.